# What can I use instead of Drive.Files.Insert() function?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My issue concerns the function `Drive.Files.insert()`,  in fact, my code runs correctly, and at the second or third launch, I get this error :

> Exception: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Empty response.

I have to save Table into a JSON to use it for the next iterations. But this error stops the process and does not save my JSON..
This is my code right below :

```
function write_json(table, fileName) {
  // define Files attributes
  var fileN = fileName + ".json"
  fileSets = {
    title: fileN,
    mimeType: 'application/json'
  };

  // write .json file

  blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(table), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
  file = Drive.Files.insert(fileSets, blob);
}
```

I don't know if it is an error due to the limit of storage ? I've seen a limit of 50MB (my JSON file size is close to this figure) or another kind of error

This is an extract of my main, showing how the function is called:

```
for (var i = iterator + 1; i < targets.length; i++) {
        if (DeltaT > limitT) break;
        var target = targets[i];
        var TableRes1 = ... ;
        deleteFileRes(1);
        write_json(TableRes1, "TableRes1"); // corresponding to our current table
        readTargets.push(i); // corresponding to the targets where we stopped
        deleteFile(1);
        write_json(readTargets, "readTargets1");

        //computation of duration
        currentT = Date.now()
        var DeltaT = currentT - startT;
}
```

The deleteFile function is used to delete the previous JSON file stored and write_json allows us to saved our new json file.

Comment: Add a [mcve] (there are missing details like how is the function being called, what arguments are passed,

Comment: If your JSON is not too large like > 25K then you can keep it in PropertiesService

Comment: My purpose is to iterate through several targets (about 29) and do multiple actions; the issue is I have to break the iteration to do not overpass the 30 min of running... That is why I implemented a break in function of time... I let you an extract of my code